# Why hibernate does not save changes to db?

Tags: java, hibernate, h2

It's my configure file
hibernate.cfg.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.h2.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">1</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
            jdbc:h2:mem:test3;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">sa</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"> create </property>
        <mapping resource="user.hbm.xml"></mapping>
        <mapping resource="role.hbm.xml"></mapping>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

When running at the first this code

`session.beginTransaction();`

```
User stock = new User();
        User stock1 = new User();
        Role role = new Role();
        role.setId(54l);
        role.setName("student");
        session.save(role);
        stock.setBirthday(new Date(56 + 65));
        stock.setEmail("emaill");
        stock.setFirstName("dima");
        stock.setPassword("1");
        stock.setRole(role);
        System.out.println(stock.getId());

        stock1.setBirthday(new Date(56 + 65));
        stock1.setEmail("emassill");
        stock1.setFirstName("dima");
        stock1.setPassword("1");
        stock1.setRole(role);
        System.out.println(stock.getId());
        session.save(stock);
        session.save(stock1);
        session.getTransaction().commit();

        JdbcUserDao dao = new JdbcUserDao();
        System.out.println(dao.findByEmail("emassill").getFirstName());
        System.out.println(dao.findAll().get(0).getFirstName());`
```

Output is:
 dima
 dima

If I saved only one user, `dao.findAll().size()` gives "1", make a long story short, changes to db aren't saved. 
Why is this?

For findAll() I use DriverManager.getConnection() and so on

```
@Override
public List<User> findAll() {
    List<User> result = new ArrayList<User>();
    try {
        connection = createConnection();
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery(FIND_ALL);
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            User temp = new User();
            temp.setId(resultSet.getLong(8));
            temp.setLogin(resultSet.getString(2));
            temp.setPassword(resultSet.getString(3));
            temp.setEmail(resultSet.getString(4));
            temp.setFirstName(resultSet.getString(5));
            temp.setLastName(resultSet.getString(6));
            temp.setBirthday(resultSet.getDate(7));
            Role tempRole = new Role();
            JdbcRoleDao jdbcRoleDao = new JdbcRoleDao();
            tempRole = jdbcRoleDao.findById(resultSet.getLong("id_role"));
            temp.setRole(tempRole);
            result.add(temp);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        myRollback();
        log.error(e, e);
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } finally {
        close();
    }
    return result;
}

public Connection createConnection() throws SQLException {
    url = "jdbc:h2:mem:test3;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false";// "jdbc:h2:./first";
    driver = "org.h2.Driver";
    login = "sa";
    password = "1";
    // init();
    try {

        Class.forName(driver);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        log.error(e, e);
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, login,
            password);
    RunScript.execute(url, login, password, SCHEMA,
            Charset.forName("UTF-8"), false);
        return connection;
}
```

My project used jdbcUserDao and i trying to use hibernateUserdao

P.S.
yes, there is text from my console:

```
Hibernate: alter table USER drop constraint FK_32nqg51ic2mg57ysalv1wnmdc if exists
Hibernate: drop table ROLE if exists
Hibernate: drop table USER if exists
Hibernate: create table ROLE (id bigint generated by default as identity, name varchar(45) not null, primary key (id))
Sep 29, 2014 7:49:19 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport perform
ERROR: HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table USER drop constraint FK_32nqg51ic2mg57ysalv1wnmdc if exists
Sep 29, 2014 7:49:19 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport perform
ERROR: Table "USER" not found; SQL statement:
alter table USER drop constraint FK_32nqg51ic2mg57ysalv1wnmdc if exists [42102-181]
Hibernate: create table USER (id bigint generated by default as identity, login varchar(45) not null, password varchar(45) not null, email varchar(45) not null, first_name varchar(45) not null, last_name varchar(45) not null, birthday date not null, id_role bigint not null, primary key (id))
Hibernate: alter table ROLE add constraint UK_9glod3qre7ighyp4ci4t6fcoy  unique (name)
Hibernate: alter table USER add constraint UK_slockai06wyhy7i5c8vnd2o31  unique (login)
Hibernate: alter table USER add constraint UK_oso07pudw19e66bs4yp8hwpux  unique (email)
Hibernate: alter table USER add constraint FK_32nqg51ic2mg57ysalv1wnmdc foreign key (id_role) references ROLE
Sep 29, 2014 7:49:19 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport execute
INFO: HHH000230: Schema export complete
Hibernate: insert into ROLE (id, name) values (null, ?)
546
546
Hibernate: insert into USER (id, login, password, email, first_name, last_name, birthday, id_role) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into USER (id, login, password, email, first_name, last_name, birthday, id_role) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
dima
dima
```

public class User {
    private Long id;
    ...
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

```
....

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setBirthday(Date arg0) {
    birthday = arg0;
}

public void setFirstName(String arg0) {
    firstName = arg0;
}
```

...
}
Role similar

Comment: Could you please post your findAll() code?

Comment: Are you able to see insert query in your console when you execute code?

Comment: please put your entity class Role and User code also?

Comment: What is the use of Hibernate if you are pulling the elements manually using JDBC from the DB? Check your database for the values that are inserted, they should be in the DB. There is a problem with your findAll() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem in "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" create

Creates new db in every time you start your application.
Must be "update" instead "create"